# How to add windows as second OS to ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, dualboot

I have a ssd drive and i have ubuntu OS installed on it and now i want to add windows 10 to it as dual boot but the way i found on the internet is to install windows first the then REINSTALL the ubuntu .. i dont want to reinstall ubuntu as i have lots of apps and configrations on it. so can i make two partitions from my ssd drive and install windows to the second partition ?? or the system will not be apple to boot ?

Comment: Another way, if Ubuntu is your prime system, is to install VMware Workstation, and install Windows 10 as a Virtual Machine. This work well. I use VMware to host Linux (other way around from you) and I am in Kali now.

Comment: I want to to make windows is also my prime os but i am not sure that dividing the ssd into two partitions and install windows to the second one will work

Comment: You can try using VMware Converter to make a VM of the Ubuntu system. I have not done this with Linux. Virtual machines is a good way to go overall.

Comment: Do you have an option to add a second HDD or SSD? Then you can unplug the Ubuntu drive while installing Windows on the other one, which is a much safer option.

Comment: @Blue_Fire you can partition and install windows . No problem with that. Just some more steps after installation to get grub back after windows installation.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/6317/1095264 and https://askubuntu.com/q/129058/1095264

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Install them in multi boot
- Install windows in a virtual machine

The first one If you install windows later is not recommended, you can have problems if you install Ubuntu after Windows, so you can backup image as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later). Then first install windows and restore ubuntu from the disk image.

But as you said that you want to make Windows your main OS, then it will not be good option to virtualize using second option.